# Multiple buttons and onClick in Android

Tags: android, webview, onclicklistener

So, I have an Android app as part of a project. The assignment is to make an app with 4 buttons, which lead to 3 different activities, and a fourth one that would serve as an Exit function.
I have the exit function working, and have tried to make the first button work but it keeps crashing.

This button should lead to an activity that would be a primitive web browser, with an edittext for the url, a go button and a webview to display the page. Yet, I cannot even get there.

When I click on the button that is meant to go to this activity I get a error that the app has stopped.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    TextView naslov = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.naslovActivity);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Podaci", 0);
    naslov.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("IME_PREZIME", "N/A"));

    Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
    Button web = (Button) findViewById(R.id.webBtn);

    web.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("INFOR", "Before intent");
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebActivity.class);
            Log.i("INFOR", "Middle");
            startActivity(myIntent);
            Log.i("INFOR", "After intent");
        }
    });
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            myIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
    }
```

So I put those logs in there to see how far the code goes. It logs the first and second one but never the third, so there seems to be an issue with the startActivity(myIntent).

Any ideas? Could the exit function be interfering with it? I have two more buttons and activities to do, but am afraid to start since I can't even get this one working.

Comment: I would change `getApplicationContext()` to `view.getContext()` and post the logcat from the crash. And, no, the exit `Listener` shouldn't have anything to do with it. And make sure that `WebActivity` is declared in your `manifest.xml`.

Comment: Can you post the WebActivity class, probably something there that makes the app crash, and it will be very helpful if you can post also the logcat about the error message Some tips to make your code simpler :
on your layout activity_b.xml : ... <Button ... android:onClick="buttonOnClick" /> ... and on your Activity, remove the onClick part and implement a new method : public void buttonOnClick(View view) { switch(view) { case web : //web button clicked, do something break; case exit : //exit button clicked, do something break; default : //do something else break; } }

Comment: Always post the LogCat when a run time error happens. e.g. crash or "app has stopped" errors. Only then we can help.

Comment: I considered using the switch case but first I want to make sure it works this way and then I can make shorter code. Turns out it was my mistake for not adding the new activity in the manifest...

Answer (score 0):

Change the below,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, WebActivity.class);
```

or even to view.getContext() as codeMagic suggested.

And, one more thing try implementing OnClickListener and calling onClick also once by,

```
exit.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then in onClick check which button called it by,

```
 @override
 onClick(View v){
    switch(c.getId()){
       case R.id.exitBtn:
        //your code
        break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok with your code in the `WebActivity.class` you probably forgot to put the activity in the android manifest, like this:

`<activity android:name=".WebActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>`

Advice: Don't use balkan language for variable names, when you get a job as a software developer, you will probably name variables, comments, etc. in english, or even post it on stackoverflow asking for help :) Start better practice asap.

Comment: I live in the Balkans so that's why I use it as variable names, easier for myself to keep track of what's what.
And yes, it was the android manifest. I didn't add the new activity...guess that's the price of being a newbie. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! Its not being a newbie. Forgetting simple things is a common programmer issue, so I think that you're on the right way.I live in the Balkans as well ;)